# AdMob not loading in Java based Game App

Tags: java, android, admob

So I have been struggling with this one for a while.  I am trying to load an AdMob banner ad in my Android Game App.  I followed the tutorials to the proverbial t and I consistently get this error:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

I have verified that the latest version of Play Services was included in the project (9.6.0).  My Firebase is up-to-date and I included the core, auth, and ad libraries in my gradle. I also defined authentication methods from within Firebase too. My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    PApplet fragment;
    private static final String MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = "main_fragment";
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private AdView adView;
    int viewId = 0x1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(View.generateViewId());

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment = new box_jump();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(frame.getId(), fragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        } else {
            fragment = (PApplet) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-2885131178882767~7287529334");


        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2885131178882767/3137714538");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(frame);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        mainLayout.addView(adView, adParams);

        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    public void showAd() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("4B8A8368A73BDA47066700EA90CB50DB").build());
    }
    public void hideAd() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any and all help and would be glad to verify any information that you may need.

Comment: For getting effect google play service will take min 10 min.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: you created google-service.josn from google console and you included in app. so it will take 10min time to get effected and will display ads.

Comment: I understand that, its been several days since I started this process.  So I've waited.

Comment: Can you try adding in xml and check whether ads is getting displayed or not?

Comment: I just tried it and i get the same error

Comment: how's showad() called? i don't see that code

Comment: Its called from within the game applet class when the title screen is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out the problem.  It was actually quite simple, the phone I was testing on had AdAway on it and even though I uninstalled it, I did not disable it before hand.  Furthermore, the emulator I was running the app on did not have Google Play Services installed.  Rectifying both resulted in the ads working.